# Excel Pricing sheet-Looking for formula that has if, search, then and vlookup all in one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vlookup

So I'm making a Pricing spread sheet for service rendered. The spread sheet has the names of my items, their sub-class, location, and two different prices because not for each piece can we preform two types of services we do.

I have a second sheet were I have made a table of prices with the sub-class name of the items in the pricing spread sheet. I use a vlookup function to add in the prices from the second sheet to the pricing spread sheet. Reason is that I have 1000s of pieces some are the same items just different sub-class names because of what they are hooked up with.

My question is: is it possible to create an if(search, then and vlookup) function.

what I want it to do is: have it look in the (Sub-class) cell if it finds a word like "Spare" then it puts a $0 in pricing if it does not say that then it looks in the (items name) cell and preforms the vlookup function.

Answer (score 0):

your formula should be something like

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("spare",B2)), "0", VLOOKUP(conditions))`

assuming B is the sub-class column

This tests if "spare" is one of the words in B2 and returns either 0 or a VLOOKUP result

Comment: Would the B2="Spare" work if I'm looking for the word with in a phrase in that cell?

Comment: Like B2 say "spare breaker" I just want to know if is has the word spare then it has to show a "0" if not then the vlookup would apply

Comment: in that case you need to use

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("spare",B2)), "0", VLOOKUP(conditions))`